# php variable "lost in translation"

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

Here is the trouble:

I've got 4 files:

**research.php**: role: send *id* to **profil.php** (that's fine).

**profil.php**: display data based on *id*

**profil.php** includes **map.view.php** that itself calls **map_controller.php** trough

```
    downloadUrl("map_controller.php", function(data) {}
```

The **map_controller.php** generates the xml data needed in **map.view.php**. To do so, it needs *id* from **profil.php**.

**Question**: Ho to pass the *id* variable in map_controller.php?

Many thanks.

Comment: Аre you using any custom or public template engine?
Logically, you need to pass $id to map.view.php and then send it to map_controller.php using this Javascript function(I suppose it is).

Comment: Yes, you normally close/remove it if it was a duplicate. I just closed it now against the duplicate you named.

Comment: Thank you! I'll know it for next time.